# cannot install python-dotenv

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, dotenv

I wanna use dotenv in python. for installation, I type `pip3 install python-dotenv` in windows command prompt. It gives the requirements are installed. but when running

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

girves the error

```
No module named 'dotenv'
```

I tried to uninstall dotenv and install again, but it didn't work.
is there any other way of installing python packages in spyder?
or how I can fix this issue?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to learn how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the **3** in your pip command:

```
pip3 install python3-dotenv
```

It's very important. Or, if that didn't work, try using it the `python` command way.

```
python -m pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: now I used python -m pip install python-dotenv the result was: requirement already satisfied. ut again it does not recognize the dot env

Comment: I think you mean 3 in `pip3`, not `python3-dotenv`

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this : https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

```
pip3.9 install python-dotenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an virtual environment?
If yes then you have to enter into the virtual environment via `source <path-to-venv>/bin/activate` and then execute the `pip3` command.

You will know that you are in a virtual environment if your shell has an `(source)` tag before the normal header.

Edit:

A bit more about virtual environment:

An virtual environment is an own instance of compiler. It is isolated from the systems libraries and the compiler. The advantage is that you don't have any other libraries which you might not need. In addition to that it doesn't matter where you execute the code if you use the same environment it will bring the same result (except for OS differences).

How to detect it:
Mostly you will find an `venv` or `env` directory in your project folder. Now if you execute the script than it depends if you use the virtual environment. Most IDEs create und use it then (like pycharm). Not every IDE lets you know what venv you use.

You can of course try it out manually by starting it via the terminal (where you have the `source` indication).

Pycharms terminal function shows you a terminal where you can see this `source` tag. From this you also can then execute `pip3` commands to install new libraries to this virtual environment.

Comment: I'm new to python and I don't know I'm using a virtual environment or not. How I can chack the header?

Comment: can you explain more how I can enter into the virtual environment?

Comment: thank you. I use spyder and yet I cannot find whether I'm using a virtual environment or not. but for other packages like matplot I didn't have any problem :(